# How slide right to left Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some problem with this slide problem.
Can anyone help change Left panel to right panel?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style> 

.left, .hidden {
    float: left;
    height:350px;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:1;
}

.hidden {
    width:7%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1000px;
    background:grey;
    color:#000;
}


.clear {
    clear:both;
}


    </style>


     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="hidden">Show Me</div>
<div class="left">Left panel</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<a href="#" id="slide">Show/hide Slide Panel</a>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the link can see in this Jsfiddle Link:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/
```

I have some problem with this slide problem.
Can anyone help change Left panel to right panel?I have some problem with this slide problem.
Can anyone help change Left panel to right panel?I have some problem with this slide problem.
Can anyone help change Left panel to right panel?

Comment: "Some problem" how specific. Repeating your question doesn't make us too excited to help, by the way. Be professional about it!

Comment: there is not clear what you really whant...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want but I see the same sentence repeated the whole time. Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: Your CSS stated in the above text is not the same as the CSS stated in the JsFiddle. Keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your css properties from 'left' to 'right'. do the same in your jQuery animate code.

```
.left, .hidden {
    float: left;
    height:350px;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:1;
}

.hidden {
    width:25%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    right:-1000px;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}

.right {
    width:50%;
    float: right;
    height:350px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/1763/

Comment: If i want using just using mouse touch on the link can slide the div?can

Answer (score 0):

Just changed your width from 25% to 50%... You can see that in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTFq/1765/)

Here is the code that I changed:

```
.hidden {
    width:50%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1000px;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}
```